# JavaFX Scene Builder 2.0 crashes with custom control

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder

I made a custom control (extends Label) with TextFormatter
that run fine. But if I import it to Scene Builder and
insert it to AncorPane, SceneBuilder closes without any
message. Log file says nothing.
I simplified the code and realised two classes. See below.
NewClass raises SceneBuilder crash, NewClass1 not.
I realised that it depends also on container:
AncorPane,Pane, TilePane,TabPane raises crash but GridPane not.

Any idea to solve the problem?

Code:

```
import javafx.scene.control.TextFormatter;

public class NewClass extends javafx.scene.control.Label{
    TextFormatter t;
    public void x(TextFormatter o) {
        t = o;
    }
    public NewClass(){ super();}
}

public class NewClass1 extends javafx.scene.control.Label{
    TextFormatter t;
    public void x(Object o) {
        t = (TextFormatter)o;
    }
    public NewClass1(){ super();}
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you haven't upgraded to Gluon's scenebuilder? http://gluonhq.com/labs/scene-builder/

Comment: Thanks. It seems to be the solution.@SedrickJefferson